# Extract two numbers form a string and add them together

Tags: python

This is probably very simple but I find that I'm confused.  I have the following string:

```
output = ['traff-05-2021=38540:2120 33078:1799 38785:2022 31420:1759 41613:2220 31805:1908 37151:2055 42374:2252 45631:2335 42688:2099 46200:2283 40684:2188 22394:1117 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 [492363:26157]\n']
```

What I would like to do is to extract the last two numbers in the string (492363 and 26157 in the above example), add them together  and save the sum as "traffic".
I will then write the value "traffic" to a text file.  The numbers in the string will constantly change but the placement will always be the same.

Would someone please help me with the correct syntax?  Thanks!

Comment: `sum(map(int, re.search(r"\[(\d+):(\d+)\]$", output).groups()))` or `sum(map(int, output[output.rfind("[") + 1: output.rfind("]")].split(":")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` and `regular expressions` as follows.

```py
traffic = reduce(lambda a,b: int(a)+int(b), re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',output[0]).group(1).split(":"))
```

We use `\[(.*?)\]` to match everything between square brackets and then split the string into an array using `:` as a delimiter. Then, we use `reduce` to reduce everything to a single value by summing them up.

Comment: Thanks David!  Worked like a charm after I found all of my syntax typos!